# Lookup not working as lookup variables can differ in name

Tags: r, ms-access, lookup, rodbc

I work a lot with databases that I have not created myself. In the databases data is often coded, e.g. male = 1, female = 2. I create a lot of dynamic reports, which need the actual level names, rather then the coding of the levels of a variable. I have been recoding every level of a variable by hand, but there must be a way to do this in a more automated way.

The key to find out what the coding actually is is this provided in a seperate table. When I import that data into R via RODBC, the tables include 1's and 2's in the column (for example) Gender. I am trying to find a way to transform them into Male and Female via a lookup table with some nasty characteristics.

In this case the data file would look something like:

| ID | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

and the lookup table would like this:

| Name | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gender | 1 | Male |
| Gender | 2 | Female |
| VariableX | 1 | whatever |
| VariableX | 2 | whatever |
| VariableX | 3 | whatever |

So I want to look up the Description in the lookup table by matching the code with the values found in data$Gender using a link between the two tables based on the variable name of the data file and the Name column in the lookup-table. I can do this by running for each of my variables:

> data$Gender<- lookup(data$Gender, subset(lookuptable,Name=="Gender"))
> (lookup being a function in the package 'epicalc')

Its all about this the 'Name == "Gender"' bit... If the variable name and the string in the column Name are the same, its not a big problem to make a loop that runs over all variable names. However, in my case, the name of strings in the column Name often does not match the name of the variable. So what do we do when the lookup table is like this:

| Name | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sex | 1 | Male |
| Sex | 2 | Female |
| VariableX | 1 | whatever |
| VariableX | 2 | whatever |
| VariableX | 3 | whatever |

In Access, the link between the lookup-table and the table which contains the actual data is via the 'Row Source' line in the 'Lookup' tab in the design of a table. This Row Source is specified at the level of the variable, as different variables will require different lookup values (which in my case can be found in 1 lookup table).

I guess my question would be solved if there is a way to import this Row source row into R, which specifies (in the example above) that Gender is actually called Sex in the lookup table.

If you'd like to know, the Row Source line (which can be specified for each variable in the data table) would look like this:

> SELECT lookuptable.Code, lookuptable.Description FROM [lookuptable] WHERE (((lookuptable.Name)="Sex"));

How can I solve my problem? I guess importing the Row Source line for each variable from each table in Access would be handy (if possible), but perhaps not (I don't know)...

R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
epicalc_2.15.1.0
RODBC_1.3-6

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the main difficulty you face is that you have lookup tables that include the coding for more than one variable, and sometimes you have to "tweak" the variable names so they match. One way to get around both of those issues would be to create saved queries in Access that can act as individual "lookup (pseudo-)tables" for each variable.

For example, you could create a saved query in Access named "GenderLookup" whose SQL code was

```
SELECT [Code], [Description] AS Gender
FROM [MasterLookupTableName]
WHERE [Name]="Gender"
```

...or...

```
SELECT [Code], [Description] AS Gender
FROM [MasterLookupTableName]
WHERE [Name]="Sex"
```

... (depending on which example above is actually the case), and then use that query as a "lookup table" in a JOIN, e.g.,

```
SELECT [DataTable].[ID], [GenderLookup].[Gender]
FROM [DataTable] INNER JOIN [GenderLookup]
    ON [DataTable].[Gender] = [GenderLookup].[Code]
```

...which would return....

```
ID  Gender
1   Male
2   Male
3   Female
4   Male
```

Comment: Aha, that sounds possible, but what if I have 40 tables each having 30 variables for which I have to run this? The problem is that I do not really want to look up the lookupname (in this case Sex for the variable Gender) for each variable in each table...

Comment: @Luc Well that's certainly an unenviable position to be in, but really, what are the alternatives? As remarkable as the advances in IT have been, we still have to tell computers `Exactly. What. To. Do.`. If the datasets you receive are that messed up then you have two alternatives: (1) Make them fix it, or (2) Work around it -- using the best advice you get from your friends on Stack Overflow -- and put in for the overtime, if you can. ;)